# Does one forgetting swallow another? Forgot if one davened during first 30 days after Pesach

Tags: halacha, tefilla, memory

In a general situation if someone forgot if they davened shacharit or mincha on a regular week day, they should do a *Tefilla Nedava* to make up for it<sup>1</sup> (based on a [Korban Nedava](https://halacha2go.com/?number=847)).

If someone (e.g. a sefardi) forgot if they recited *Morid Hatal* on shacharit or mincha amida, we make them say it again (מחזירין אותו) if it is within the first 30 days after Pesach before the habit would have formed to say it<sup>2</sup>.

**What happens when we combine these, and say that in the first 30 days after Pesach, one forgot if they davened?** One can then *possibly* argue a self-cancelling double-doubt: they don't know *if they are even in a "state of doubt"* about *Morid Hatal*, which is the reason for the forced repetition. Do they follow the laws of torat nedava, or "מחזירין אותו"? One nafka mina could be that if one is very sure they can't concentrate, they might not be allowed to do a *Tefilla Nedava*, but we would still make them say Amida again for the *Morid Hatal* doubt.

---

I also wonder how this would affect the situation of *Hamelech Hakadosh* in the 10 Days of Teshuva - I think the question about the double doubt would be even stronger there. However, I don't think it applies to *Ya'aleh Veyavo* in Chol Hamoed<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1 - According to Biur Halacha. See [this discussion](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/halakha/orach-chaim/prayer-and-blessings/tefillat-nedava-voluntary-prayer).

2 - [See dinonline](https://dinonline.org/2016/10/27/doesnt-know-if-he-said-mashiv-haruach/). [SA OC 114](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%252C_Orach_Chayim.114): 5,6,9; MB ibid 41, 42, MB 96:7

3 - See Rama on [SA OC 422:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%252C_Orach_Chayim.422.1)</sup>

Comment: If he’s not sure he prayed, then he’s definitely not sure he said the new additions in prayer, no?

Comment: Also, with regards to the נפקא מינה, note that the restrictions of נדבה don’t apply when recited because of a doubt.

Comment: @שלום if he isn't sure if he said Amidah (case 1), there are three possibilities: A) he said it and remembered the additions, B) he said it and forgot the additions or C) He didn't say it. If he knows he said Amidah (case 2), then it's just A and B. I don't know if C modifies/takes precedence over the quoted halachos that deal with the scenario of only A or B (case 2), nor do I know if the halachot of C are even in the same inyan (or even mention) the halachot of additions, and therefore wouldn't know that the laws of 2 are relevant to the laws of 1, or what takes priority.

Comment: @שלום good point. Even if we can't find a nafka mina, I still think the theoretical exercise is worth it for deepening our overall understanding of halacha?